# kate resolution difference with/without sudo

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to set up Raspberry Pi model 3b+ as a router. I am using Raspbian stretch and installed kate as my code editor. Then I noticed when using kate with sudo, the text and menu is smaller than without using sudo.

[image: 2 instance of kate, with and without sudo]

So I started 2 instance of kate, one with sudo and the other without sudo

- The left one is started normally (from start menu at left top)
- The right one is started with `sudo -b kate`.
- Both have the same monitor resolution (1360x768)
- Even if I zoom out on the normal kate to make the text smaller, the menu size is still larger than the one started with `sudo`

This strange behavior makes me wonder, so I have several questions:

1. Can someone explain why the text size and menu size (or app resolution) is different when starting kate with/without sudo?
2. Is it possible to make kate start with smaller text (as if started using `sudo`) by default?
3. Does this behavior applies to (some) other applications?
4. Is it possible to make other apps smaller too? Because IMO some apps also have large text.

**UPDATE:**
[image: differences]
Now I have changed both font size to 9pt and I still notice menu text are larger and the one with sudo displays 6 more lines. I still don't know what causes this behavior, but changing font size to 9 is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know kate, but presume it is a GUI application.

It is generally inadvisable to run X11 applications as root, but if you want to do so you should use `gksudo`.

Your underlying problem is probably the root environment which is not configured.
`gksudo` has options to preserve environment.

PS It seems strange to run an interactive editor in the background.

Comment: So if I use `gksudo` can I protect myself from the exploit mentioned by David?

Comment: I would like to mention that `sudo -E` will also preserve the current environment. @wthe22 All people here tell you that you should not use **root** for working. On Unix systems **root** is not a user for normal work. There are many special conditions for root that make applications work as not expected. And it is always a security risk to use **root** continuously as working user. It is only meant to configure the protected system so it can be used by normal user.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default font in Kate go to the `Settings` menu, then `Configure Kate` → `Colors & Fonts` → `Font`.

You should avoid opening GUI applications as root, since [X11 applications can be exploited this way](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/02/editing-files-as-root/).

Comment: It works, and thanks for mentioning the exploit. btw I still notice menu text are still larger, still makes me wonder what cause this to happen.